# Phase-based motion magnificaton. Why is the phase difference computed like so?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing

In the phase-based motion magnification code http://people.csail.mit.edu/nwadhwa/phase-video/, why is the phase difference between the current frame and the reference frame computed as:

```
DeltaPhase = mod(pi+angle(pyr)-angle(pyrRef), 2*pi) - pi;
```

rather than the way I understand from the paper:

```
DeltaPhase = angle(pyr) - angle(pyrRef);
```

Comment: This is a simple way of subtracting angles and ensuring the result is between `-pi` and `pi`. Consider the difference between 359 degrees and 1 degree, You could represent this as a 358 degrees or -2 degrees.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot!